# Dynamic distance calculation for route

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement a form where you enter the origin and destination and then by using the google maps javascript API, it would display the distance as the origin and destination values change. below is my code, I am able to acquire the addresses using the maps API but the part where it checks for the filling of the form to calculate the distance is not working, I think the problem is in 
line 87 -> $('#quota_form').on('input', dispdist)
here is my code below, please let me know how to fix line 87

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- head start -->
<head>
    <!-- styles -->
    <style>
        .top_margin {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .border {
            border-style: inset inset inset inset;
        }
    </style >
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB03tJHy5QUZ_L3bjn3ehSkFE5QVrcSlLo&libraries=places"></script>

    <script>
        /* When the document gets ready */
        $(document).ready (
            function initialize() {
                /* Variables */
                var origin_input = ''
                var destination_input = ''
                var prices = {
                    "choice 1": 10,
                    "choice 2": 20,
                    "choice 3": 30,
                    "choice 4": 40,
                    "choice 5":50,
                    "choice 6":60
                };
                var distance_service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                var route = {
                    origins: [],
                    destinations: [],
                    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
                    avoidHighways: false,
                    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
                }
                /* Variables */

                /* Functions */
                // Distance parser
                function getorigin() {
                    origin_input = autocomplete_origin.getPlace().formatted_address;
                }
                function getdestination() {
                    destination_input = autocomplete_destination.getPlace().formatted_address;
                }
                function parse_distance(response, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        var origins = response.originAddresses;
                        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
                        for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                                var element = results[j];
                                var dist = element.distance.text;
                                var duration = element.duration.text;
                                var from = origins[i];
                                var to = destinations[j];
                            }
                        }
                        $('#distance').text(dist);
                    }
                }
                function dispdist() {
                    /* distance calculation */
                    route.origins.push(origin_input);
                    route.destinations.push(destination_input);
                    distance_service.getDistanceMatrix (route, parse_distance);
                }
                /* Functions */

                /* addresses auto complete initialization */
                autocomplete_origin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('origin'));
                autocomplete_destination = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('destination'));
                autocomplete_origin.addListener('place_changed', getorigin);
                autocomplete_destination.addListener('place_changed', getdestination);

                /* display distance */
                $('#quota_form').on('input', dispdist)
            });

    </script>
</head>
<!-- head end -->

<!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!-- body start -->
<body>

<div class="container-fluid top_margin">
    <form id="quota_form">
        <!-- Origin input -->
        <div id="q" class="form-group">
            <label for="origin">Origin</label>
            <input id="origin" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter origin address">
        </div>

        <!-- Destination input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="destination">Destination</label>
            <input id="destination" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter destination address">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Distance output -->
            <label>Distance</label>
            <output id="distance" form="quota_form" class="border" for="origin destination">Distance Determination</output>
        </div>

        <!-- Package size choice -->
        <label>Package size</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="packageSize" class = "btn-group">
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 1</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 2</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 3</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 4</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 5</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">choice 6</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Quota Output -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quota</label>
            <output id="quota" form="quota_form" class="border" for="distance packageSize">Quota Determination</output>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
<!-- body end -->
</html>
```

Comment: what exacly is the problem at "line 87"?

Comment: There is no response to filling both the origin field and the destination field

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: ya, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'element.distance.text') for line 63, this error happens as soon as I enter something in the origin and destination fields

Comment: so `element.distance` is not an object

Comment: ya, it appears so, so element.distance.text should give me a string that says (10 miles) for example

Comment: so basically, what I want to do is that my form with id = 'quota_form' should call my distance calculation function only when both the origin and destination fields are filled and not for any other condition